# Can we create a global redux store which can be accessible in both react and angular apps?

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux, react-redux, ngrx

I'm working on web components.

I've created a react component with redux and exported it as web component. It is working fine.

Now I've a component written in Angular, but I'm not sure how can I access the store created in react component in my angular component?

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) as described [here](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/) on your react app and access it on your Angular code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use  browser `local storage` like this:

Create a localStorage name/value pair with name="lastname" and value="Smith", then retrieve the value of "lastname" and insert it into the element with id="result":

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

keep in mind that:

> The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data
>   will not be deleted automatically when the browser is closed, and will be available
>   the next day, week, or year.

*I am not sure if its the best practice or not*

For more details on localstorage you can refer to : 
https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36/